# SpriteNodes messed up after returning to GameScene (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite, nodes, skscene

I have two scenes. GameScene and PlayScene. The GameScene is more of the "home screen" while the PlayScene is where the actual gameplay takes place. Everything is fine when transitioning to PlayScene.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playbutton {

            let scaleDown = SKAction.scaleBy(0.01, duration: 1.0)

            self.playbutton.runAction(scaleDown)

            var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size

            let transition = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Left, duration: 3)

            transition.pausesOutgoingScene = false
            skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)

        }
    }
}
```

However...when someone gets sent back to the GameScene after hitting the "replay" button in PlayScene, all the nodes in GameScene are messed up. Their sizes are enlarged and one node is even reversed backwards.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

        isFingerTouching = true


    if self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation) == self.facebookButton {
        facebookButtonPushed()
    }

    if self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation) == self.twitterButton {
        twitterButtonPushed()
    }

    if self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation) == self.replay {

        var scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        let skView = self.view as SKView!
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size

        let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0)
        transition.pausesOutgoingScene = false
        skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)

    }

}
```

I'm not sure how this happens, but any sort of help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. You need to set the [scaleMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/scaleMode) (look in here for more information on "scaleMode"). Just put this code in your viewDidLoad() for swift:

```
self.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

Hope this helped.